# GCC but not Clang changes ref-qualifier of function type for a pointer to qualified member function

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

Following snippet compiles in Clang but not in GCC 12.

```
// function type (c style)
//typedef  int fun_type() const&;
// C++ style
using fun_type = int() const&; 

struct S {
    fun_type fun;
};

int S::fun() const& {
    return 0;
}

int main() 
{
    fun_type  S::* f  = &S::fun;  
}
```

Produces error in GCC:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:21:25: error: cannot convert 'int (S::*)() const &' to 'int (S::*)() const' in initialization
   21 |     fun_type  S::* f  = &S::fun;
      |                         ^~~~~~~
```

Declaration of S should be equivalent of following declaration

```
struct S {
    int  fun() const&;
};
```

Using this declaration doesn't change behaviour of either compiler. Is this a bug in compiler's translation module related to an under-used feature of language? Which compiler is correct standard-wise?

Comment: Looks like a GCC bug to me.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Sadly Bugzilla (at least GCC one)  restricts\disallows account creation on bug tracker for my location, and my emails were ignored or filtered.  Can someone submit that?

Comment: Done: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=105967

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which compiler is correct standard-wise?

Clang is correct in accepting the program. The program is well-formed as `fun_type  S::* f` is equivalent to writing:

```
int (S::*f)() const &
```

which can be initialized by the **initializer** `&S::fun`.

Comment: Yeah, sadly there is no way I know of to amend the case of named function type - which can be useful to avoid that "emoji code".

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Yes, and gcc only have problem when using `&` qualifier in the member function. If we remove the `&` from the mem function it [works](https://godbolt.org/z/Pcnv3nvoc) without any problem.